# Defined function is miscounting number of upper/lowercase characters

Tags: python, function, for-loop, user-defined-functions

```
def letcheck(a):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for letter in a:
        if a.islower():
            lower += 1
        else:
            upper += 1
    print('The number of lowercase letters is', lower)
    print('The number of uppercase letters is', upper)
    return

letcheck('My name is Slugcat')
```

Hi there. I imagine this is very basic for most of you so forgive me but I can't figure out why my function is outputting this.

```
The number of lowercase letters is 0
The number of uppercase letters is 18

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why has it counted all characters as uppercase? Please help.
P.S. is there any way to stop it from counting the spaces in the string? Thank you very much.

Comment: Read this again: `for letter in a: if a.islower(): ...`

Comment: In you own words, where the code says `if a.islower():`, what do you expect this to mean? In particular, what do you think will be the value of `a` at this point in the program? Will it be a single letter from the input, or will it be the entire string? Therefore, what will happen when trying to use `.islower` on it? Therefore, what happens to the `lower` and `upper` variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `if a.islower()` to `if letter.islower()` as you want to check the case for each letter not `a` which is the sentence itself. Spaces are counted as uppercase so for an accurate reading loop over the sentence with the whitespace removed.

```
def letcheck(a):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    #Loop over sentence with whitespace removed
    for letter in a.replace(" ",""):
        if letter.islower():
            lower += 1
        else:
            upper += 1
    print('The number of lowercase letters is', lower)
    print('The number of uppercase letters is', upper)
    return

letcheck('My name is Slugcat')
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that

Comment: @slugcat You're welcome. Have updated the answer for more accuracy. Please mark the answer as best answer if it has helped.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not write answers for problems caused by a simple typo - they are not on-topic questions here.